# Symfony 3 ManyToOne relationship empty related Collection

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, one-to-many

Using Symfony 3.4, I am saving an Entity that has a ManyToOne relationship. In the database the relationship is saved properly but in the Entity the related property remains an empty Collection instead of being populated with the related entities. I need this so I can return a complete JSON object as an API response. Complete means containing also the related properties.

I have also tried with `fetch=EAGER` but it does not change the result.

**User.php**

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PGS", mappedBy="user", fetch="EAGER")
 */
private $pgs;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->pgs = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

**PGS.php**

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="G", fetch="EAGER")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="gId", referencedColumnName="id")
 * @ORM\Id
 *
 */
private $g;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="pgs", fetch="EAGER")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="userId", referencedColumnName="id")
 * @ORM\Id
 *
 */
private $user;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="S", fetch="EAGER")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="sId", referencedColumnName="id")
 * @ORM\Id
 *
 */
private $s;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="P", fetch="EAGER")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="pId", referencedColumnName="id")
 * @ORM\Id
 *
 */
private $p;
```

To abbreviate the code immagine the 3 entities P, G, and S to have the corresponding `OneToMany` targeting PGS (they are anyway probably not relevant to this problem).

**UserManager.php**

```
 // $user is a valid User entity constructed before. I want to store it.
 $this->entityManager->persist($user);

 foreach ($p in $arrayOfP) {
      // $g and $s are known and valid
      $pgs = new PGS();
      $pgs->setUser($user);
      $pgs->setG($g);
      $pgs->setS($s);
      $pgs->setP($p);
      $this->entityManager->persist($pgs);
 }

 $this->entityManager->flush();

 // At this point I would expect the $user object to contain the pgs
 // Instead I get an empty collection.
 dump(count($user->getPGS())) // returns 0

 // in the DB both User and PGS are properly created
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: Yes, same problem even re-fetching the user. (btw typo `getId()`)

Comment: You persist user entity before adding PGS. Try a cascade={"persist"} in your entities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have in the PGS entity in setUser method something like this

```
public function setUser(UserInterface $user){
$user->addPgs($this);
$this->user = $user;
}
```

I think that you have to add, and after that if you dump you should have a collection.

Comment: Marking this as accepted. I was thinking Doctrine would take care automatically. I didn't know about the 'adders' and 'removers'!

Comment: Inside the Symfony documentation (https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/associations.html#mapping-the-manytoone-relationship) the created `setCategory()` method of the owning side does not call the `addProduct()` method of the inverse side. So this solution is only a workaround and it should work as documented.

But I now have a case, where nothing at all works, the collection remains empty, until I re-fetch it. Neither a `cascade={"persist"}`, nor persisting both entities at a later time. So sadly this solution is the only workaround I found.